# ruby on rails enable validates if condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, if-statement, model

**post.rb**

```
  @allowed_post_types = [
    'type1',
    'type2',
    'type3',
    'type4'
  ]

  #validate post type
  validates :post_type, :presence => true, :inclusion=> { :in => @allowed_post_types }, :if => :valid_post_type?



  def valid_post_type?
    self.post_type != 'type5'
  end
```

how can i enable `validates :post_type` line of code whenever the `:post_type` is not **type5** ?

Tried the above but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
validates :post_type, 
          :presence => true, 
          :inclusion=> { :in => @allowed_post_types }, 
          :if => lambda { |a| a[:post_type] != "type5" }
```